# Add subquery in query - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

My query return all days in month.

```
SELECT 
       EXTRACT( DAY FROM day ) ||' '|| substr(TO_CHAR( day, 'fmDAY' ),0,3) AS day,
       EXTRACT( DAY FROM day ) as day_id
FROM (
  WITH temp ( col ) AS (
    SELECT to_date(2, 'mm') --2 is February
    FROM   dual 
  )
  SELECT col + level - 1 AS day
  FROM   temp 
  CONNECT BY level <= last_day(col) - col + 1
  ORDER BY day
)
```

How get all days from query where DAY_ID not in ==> (Select day_id from table1)

Eg. table1 return 5,10,15

Query resault need to display all days except 5,10,15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate your calendar and then use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
WITH month ( col ) AS (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), 2 - 1)
  FROM   DUAL
),
calendar ( day, end_day ) AS (
  SELECT col, LAST_DAY(col)
  FROM month
UNION ALL
  SELECT day + INTERVAL '1' DAY, end_day
  FROM   calendar
  WHERE  day < end_day
)
SELECT EXTRACT( DAY FROM day ) ||' '|| TO_CHAR( day, 'fmDY' ) AS day,
       EXTRACT( DAY FROM day ) as day_id
FROM   calendar c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   table1 t
  WHERE  c.day = t.day_id
)
ORDER BY c.day;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 ( day_id ) AS
SELECT DATE '2021-02-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-02-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-02-15' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DAY | DAY_ID |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 MON | 1 |
> | 2 TUE | 2 |
> | 3 WED | 3 |
> | 4 THU | 4 |
> | 6 SAT | 6 |
> | 7 SUN | 7 |
> | 8 MON | 8 |
> | 9 TUE | 9 |
> | 11 THU | 11 |
> | 12 FRI | 12 |
> | 13 SAT | 13 |
> | 14 SUN | 14 |
> | 16 TUE | 16 |
> | 17 WED | 17 |
> | 18 THU | 18 |
> | 19 FRI | 19 |
> | 20 SAT | 20 |
> | 21 SUN | 21 |
> | 22 MON | 22 |
> | 23 TUE | 23 |
> | 24 WED | 24 |
> | 25 THU | 25 |
> | 26 FRI | 26 |
> | 27 SAT | 27 |
> | 28 SUN | 28 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=33631e44f1c5e9a8de3b9c5569d3e536)*

Answer (score 1):

One way to generate all rows in month for dates in another table is to use a recursive CTE:

```
create table table1 as
    select date '2021-04-16' as day_in from dual;

with cte (dte) as (
      select trunc(day_in, 'MON') as dte
      from table1
      union all
      select dte + interval '1' day
      from cte
      where dte < last_day(dte)
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7d48ac758470bc3bbadf6bc8f709b74b) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

If you want the days *not in* a table, then use:

```
with cte (dte) as (
      select date '2021-02-01' as dte
      from dual
      union all
      select dte + interval '1' day
      from cte
      where dte < last_day(dte)
     )
select dte
from cte
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.day_id = cte.dte);
```

You can also use `not exists` using your query, but I find the recursive CTE easier to follow -- and it is standard SQL.

Comment: Tnx for help but your example is different and return different resault then my request.

Comment: Your request is far from clear, so it's completely normal that any answer doesn't fit your question

Comment: @Pointer . . . Just use `not exists` or `not in`.